# Pushing Android Server App to Mobile Phones

Tags: android

I have created an Android App which consists of client and server code. If a user submit an order in the client app then I'll receive that order in the server app. I can publish the client app in the Google play without any issues but I can't publish the server app because everyone will get the user information. My question here is how to push the server app in the Android phone or any better way to handle this issue.

Comment: As far as I understand from your question, you are also trying to push the Server app to Play Store. Server apps are deployed on servers generally referred to as back-end. Your Android app works as a user-facing client interface where users interact. You may use any Cloud service to deploy the server app. Which programming language did you use for the server app?

Comment: I am not willing to push server app to play store instead I like to push it to certain people phone so, if they receive order they will get notified. If I publish server app in the playstore whoever installed this one will get order information.

Comment: OK, so your setup is that you have apps one where orders are placed and one where orders are received and both are Android applications. Well you will require a middleware to have communication between these two and which will also protect the user data. You are calling your android app as server app that got me confused.

Comment: Whats the solution for this issue?

Comment: The solution is to have a backend system where everything is stored and communicated between client apps. The real server application so to say, not the android one. It's a very different domain than developing just an android app. You can get started with Firebase which will be easy as far as I think.